# Issue building CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 and I would like to create a build of CKEditor. I've read: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_build.

First issue: I don't have any "build.sh" in my CKEditor folder. Solution: download https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/dev/builder/build.sh .

Second issue: the build.sh above is not totaly correct, I had to modify some locations (e.g. "../.." instead of "."). But I think it's now ok since I don't have messages like "file not found" anymore...

Third issue: I've several warnings like:

```
WARNING: it was impossible to update the lang property in /home/sebsheep/progs_div/albums_tests/ckeditor/release/ckeditor/plugins/youtube/plugin.js
```

Moreover, I've the impression that CKBuilder only copy my initial folder recursively, as we can see with "/ckeditor/release/ckeditor/release/ckeditor/release/ckeditor/release/ckeditor/release/ckeditor" (thoses files actually are on my disc) on this message:

```
WARNING: it was impossible to update the lang property in /home/sebsheep/progs_div/albums_tests/ckeditor/release/ckeditor/release/ckeditor/release/ckeditor/release/ckeditor/release/ckeditor/plugins/indent/plugin.js
```

Those warnings never stop, I have to C-c in order to stop the program.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that you tried to build CKEditor using a built version which obviously does not contain necessary tools.

To build CKEditor from source:

1. Clone [CKEditor development repository](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev), or just download it if you don't know git.
2. Add 3rd party plugins to the `plugins/` directory.
3. Modify `dev/builder/build-config.js` (edit the list of plugins).
4. Run `dev/builder/build.sh`